# How to stop when reaches maximum try attempts and if answer is wrong stay in the same question

Tags: java

I am trying to make a quiz in which the number increases if the answer is right, if not you will have 4 tries in each question for example 
`2 x 1 = ?`

If you answer right you must go to `2 x 2 = ?`
and so on until reaches 10. and if you answered it right you will get 5 points per question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  int points = 0;
  int multiply;


  System.out.println("please enter a number");
   int yourNumber = input.nextInt();

   for (multiply = 0; multiply<= 10; multiply++){
       int yourAnswer = yourNumber * multiply;

      System.out.println(yourNumber + " x " + multiply + " = ? ");

   int theAnswer = input.nextInt();

   for (int tries = 0; tries >= 4; tries++){
    if (theAnswer == yourAnswer){
        System.out.println("nice");
        tries++;
```

Comment: Does this code compile successfully? I do not think so. The last for iteration seems to go infinite.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi You mean it doesn't even start

Comment: Also OP you should start having `multiply = 1` other wise the result will be zero

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code is not complete, and the for loop part should be <= as you want to keep the loop while treis is smaller or equal to 4
In your case >= cannot go into the loop as tries = 0 and tries is not greater than 4
I also edit to tries = 0, <=5 as you can change directly if you want 5 attempt than it is the number

```
for (int tries = 1; tries <= 5; tries++){
if (theAnswer == yourAnswer){
    System.out.println("nice");
    points = points + 5;
    break;
    }
 else{
    System.out.println("Your answer : " + theAnswer  + " is wrong, please try again. Attempts : " + tries);
    theAnswer = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: but when you answer something wrong it goes from 1 to 3 to 5 , i want it to be 1,2,3,4 and when you reach 4 the game has to stop

Comment: opps sorry, i just mistaken increment tries myself haha, just removed that, it should be fine now

Answer (score 0):

I made this quick code to solve your problem.
It addresses to the issue of the tries and once it finishes the code breaks out.

Also  `multiply` should be set to `1` instead of `0`.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class MyClass {
 static Scanner input;
 static int tries=5;
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  input = new Scanner(System.in);

  int points = 0;



  System.out.println("please enter a number");
   int yourNumber = input.nextInt();

   for (int multiply = 1; multiply<= 10; multiply++){

       boolean ans= answer(multiply*yourNumber);
       if(ans){
          System.out.println("Nice"); 
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("Tries Exhausted!"); 
           break;
       }
   }

      //System.out.println(yourNumber + " x " + multiply + " = ? ");

   int theAnswer = input.nextInt();


}

  static boolean answer(int ans){
   int yourAnswer= input.nextInt();
   while(tries>0){
        if(ans== yourAnswer){
          tries++;
          return true;
        }
        tries--;
        System.out.println("Your answer is wrong\nYou got"+tries+"tries left!");
   }
   return false;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.